# Why is microsoft using my account for RDP connections

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have been using RDP from home pc (windows 10), but after I shifted to my laptop (windows 10) it cannot connect. [RDP image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzH49.png)

I dont want that account there. I want to connect directly, but it shows this every time. I have been using a enterprise license and I created another user account and it works, but i need it in my admin account. Please help, I want to get rid of that microsoft account from RDP.

Comment: Provide the initial screenshot from before the error, in other words, the prompt for the username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click `More options`, there's an option to connect as another user.
Click `Use a different account` and type in your credentials.

[image: RDP credentials]

If that doesn't work, click Show Options in the RDP window, and then click "Always ask for credentials" if it's not ticked by default. You can change the domain there, under the "User name".

[image: RDP show options]

[image: RDP options]

Comment: but it microsoftaccount/****** no way to get out of that.

Comment: I've updated my answer - see if you can change the domain now.

Comment: bro,, thanks for the response.. i followed the answer but i can't log in ...it says "The logon attempt failed ".

Comment: Thank you so much bro i tried this another way and succeed.Thank you so much,..